# How can I change the font of a JTable's header?

Tags: java, fonts, jtable, jtableheader

I want to set the JTable header's font.
Do you know how?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This should work:

```
    table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.ITALIC, 12));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
header.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 18));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement TableCellRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this to set all table's header's font :

```
    UIManager.put("TableHeader.font", font1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
tableName.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", 1 , 16));
```